# ¿Cómo borrar una carpeta de un repositorio de GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Busque por todos lados y siempre aparece lo mismo. Lo que yo tengo es un repositorio subido y quiero borrarle una carpeta sin tener que bajarlo y subirlo todo de nuevo. ¿Se puede hacer? Disculpen mi ignorancia soy nuevo en esto y espero no haber sido molesto ni invasivo.

- Primero me loguee
- Luego hice `git init`,
- Luego `git remote add origin <la ruta de mi repositorio>`
- Luego el comando que pase en el primer comentario y me dice

> fatal: remote origin already exists

Comment: Bueno lei que tengo que hacer :
git rm -r micarpeta

Pero no se como pararme en esa carpeta para hacer eso. Esto tratando de poner la imagen con todos los comandos que use para intentar pararme sobre esa carpeta y no pude hacerlo. Perdon.

Comment: Primero me loguie, luego hice git init, luego git remote add origin <la ruta de mi repositorio> y luego el comando que pase en el primer comentario y me dice :fatal: remote origin already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que debes hacer es:

1.- **Clona** tu repositorio en tu equipo local de esta forma:

```
git clone https://github.com/youruser/demo.git
```

2.- Una vez que hayas clonado dicho repositorio, debes dirijirte a el en tu equipo y eliminar el archivo deseado o carpeta en este caso

Y agregas el cambio hecho al *stage*:

```
git add .
```

3.- Posterior ejecutas el comando del **`commit`** así:

```
git commit -m "Eliminando una carpeta"
```

4.- Finalmente indicas la rama donde esto va a pasar así:

```
git push origin master
```

**FINAL**

En este punto **GitHub** por la consola de comandos te va a pedir tus credenciales de acceso por medio de una interfaz gráfica si estas en Windows (en Linux no se) una vez escritas le das en Aceptar y el `commit` se llevará a cabo

Comment: Buenísimo. YA voy a intentar eso. Muchisimas gracias. En un rato vuelvo confirmo si me salio ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: ¡Si! ¡Me salió muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

Para eliminar la carpeta

```
git rm -r micarpeta
```

Creamos el commit

```
git commit -m "Elimino mi carpeta"
```

y subes los cambios al repositorio con

```
git push
```

U otra manera es hacer algo parecido, pero usando el programa de github y te evitas usar los comando "[desktop github](https://desktop.github.com/)"

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que no quede rastro alguno en Github lo mejor será que borres el repositorio y lo vuelvas a subir.

Si ya hiciste lo que te respondieron, hacer git rm, commit y luego push, entonces en tu último commit esa carpeta no existe.

Un truco sería que antes de borrarlo de GitHub hagas: `git clone --depth=1 github.com/user/repo`

Esto te creará un clon local sin más que el último commit.

Entonces lo vuelves a crear en GitHub, vuelves a hacer `git remote add orgin github.com/user/repo` y `git push -u origin master`

Habrás perdido todo el historial menos el último commit, pero si en la carpeta había datos sensibles que no deben estar en internet, esta es la mejor opción